# TYPO3 Calendar Base - how to let user switch the month in List View

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I use the Calendar Base in TYPO3 7.6.
It is possible to use Fluid in the List View.
But how can I let the user change month that is shown?
In "Other views" I have checked the "Show Jumps" option, but it has no effect in the list view.

I have asked a similar question in the forum at typo3.org, but with no luck so far.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. Show jumps includes dropdown with weeks, months or years, depending on the view. What do you want to show when doing list of 20 events with pagination in the dropdown? Also as far as I see, the extension does not use Fluid, but old style marker templates.

Comment: Fluid is an option for listView. I can set listView to show events for current month, but I woulkd like to give the user the opprtunity to se what happend last month or what vil happen next month.